# AX 2012 : increase EDT length for userid

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

there is a table `sysuserinfo`, the filed `ID` holds the id of the user which is of type extend data type `userid`, the length of this EDT is 8 by default, however, some users may have longer userid so I want to increase the EDT length.

however, going to AOT >> EDT, am not able to find the `userid` EDT, is it feasible to increase the userid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UserId` is defined in AOT > System Documentation > Types > UserId. It is not possible to increase its length.

> some users may have longer userid

UserId doesn't *have* to be longer as it is a unique user identifier in AX not depending on other Id's. Maybe you are confusing it with full user name `UserInfo.name` (which can be 40 characters long) or `UserInfo.networkAlias` (80 characters long)?